# Problems in change text of a textview

Tags: android

I have a problem in change a text of a textview in android, i'm starting in android, ok I want do a chat with sockets, I made the socket and connected on server but i can't change the text of the textview, ok this is the code:

```
public class Cliente extends Activity {
    Button conect;
    Button env;
    EditText ip;
    EditText nome;
    EditText msg;
    String nome_txt;
    String ip_txt;
    Socket cl;
    String texto = "";
    TextView log;
    boolean a = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);
        conect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.conect);
        env = (Button) findViewById(R.id.env);
        msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_tx);
        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nm_tx);
        log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log);
        conect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ip_txt = ip.getText().toString();
                nome_txt = nome.getText().toString();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_cliente);
                Thread th =new Thread(new Ct());
                Log.d("Iniciado", "th");
                log.setText("asd");
                th.start();
            }

        });
        env.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    envMSG(msg.getText().toString());
                    msg.setText("");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void envMSG(String msg) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(cl.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes(msg + '\n');
    }
    public String serOUT() {
        try{
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cl.getInputStream()));
            if (inFromServer.ready()) {
                String texto = inFromServer.readLine();
                return texto;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

   public class Ct extends Thread implements Runnable{
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               cl = new Socket(ip_txt, 1111);
               envMSG(nome_txt);
               do{
                   String tx = serOUT();
                   if (tx != null) {
                       texto += tx + "\n";
                       log.setText(texto);

                           envMSG("ola");

                   }
                   Log.d("Status",cl.isClosed()+"");
                   this.sleep(10);

               }while (true);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Please tell the error reason, and show examples.

Thanks for Reading.
ass.:Lucas Avelino

Comment: Is there anything in logcat to indicate what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cant set text inside thread, you have to ovveride runOnUiThread method and try to set text in this method.

```
public class Ct extends Thread implements Runnable{
   @Override
   public void run() {
       try {
           cl = new Socket(ip_txt, 1111);
           envMSG(nome_txt);
           do{
               String tx = serOUT();
               if (tx != null) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      texto += tx + "\n";
                      log.setText(texto);
                      envMSG("ola");
                    }
                });


               }
               Log.d("Status",cl.isClosed()+"");
               this.sleep(10);

           }while (true);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```